# Match the first string that starts with // up to the first space with regex

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm trying to extract the first string starting with // to the first space.
So far I have ^(\A\w+) but it only gives me the first word and I cant figure out how to tell it to also match starting with //

For example:

```
#Sample text
//AnyNumberORLetter notthis <-- only want to match //AnyNumberORLetter  
//HELLO WORLD
```

---

Edit typo

Edit 2: sorry I am using Ansible with regex

```
    - name: "replace job name"
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: "{{jcl_path}}"
        regexp: '^(\A\w+)'
        line: '{{job_name}}'
        group: dart
        mode: g+rw
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 3):

This captures your target as group 1:

```
(//\S+)([\s\S]*)
```

and remove `line:` and add `replace: '\1 {{job_name}}'\2`

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/nT5g4z3Vr80z7W).

regex breakdown:

- `^` means start
- `\S` means a non-whitespace character
- `+` means one or more of the preceding expression
- `[\s\S]*` means the rest of the input (works with any flavour of regex)

Comment: Also this matches another line I just need it to match the first match found

Comment: You may need to remove `line:` and add `replace: '\1 {{job_name}}'`

Comment: I switched over to replace and your expression. It replaces the whole file...

Comment: See further edits!

Answer (score 3):

To also start with `//` you can make the `//` optional:

```
^(?://)?\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wTA0AB/1)

To only start with `//`

```
^//\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bVrztJ/1)

Comment: How would I tell it to only match to the first found?

Comment: @Mr.White If you want to match the first occurrence at the start of the string, then `\A(?://)?\w+`

Comment: The  Your expression worked! Combined with Bohemian suggestion to switch to replace.